# Using values obtained in a set, push values from an array that contain that set's index into separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, set

### The Question

So I have a large data table and it contains some data that I am not really concerned with and some that isn't so I am trying to populate the data that I do care about into a smaller, more compact table. By using RegEx I am able to find the indexes that contain the information that I do care about and I am placing them in a set. A snippet of how I am doing this is shown below

#### Importing the Excel Sheet

```js
onFileChange(event: any) 
  {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => 
    {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      this.data = <Array>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, 
      {header: 1, blankrows: true })); 
    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);  
  }
```

What this does is it reads the excel sheet and makes it into an object of arrays where each array is a row of the excel sheet. So to find what I want I created the following function"

```js
columnsWithManufacturer()
  {
    var someManufacturers = [//list of a bunch of regex phrases//];
    var manColumnIndexes = new Set();

    for (var manufacturer of someManufacturers)
    {
      for (const row of this.data)
      {
        for (var cell=0; cell< row.length; cell++)
        {
          if (manufacturer.test(row[cell]))
          {
            manColumnIndexes.add(cell)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return manColumnIndexes
  }
```

The value of cell is actually the column value in the excel sheet where the data is located and the set is all of the unique column numbers where the data is found. What I am trying to do is to push basically each column that I have found into a separate array. So if information was found in columns 14, 16, and 17 for instance, I want to push all the data from column 14 into an array , all the data from column 16 into an array, and all the data from column 17 into an array using a separate function.

### What I've tried

Creating a new function now I have tried the following:

```js
pushIntoSeparateArrays()
  {
    var manufacturersArrays = [this.primaryManufactArray,this.altManufactArr,this.altManufactArr2,this.altManufactArr3]

    var manufactIndexes = this.columnsWithManufacturer()

    for (var array of manufacturersArrays)
    {
      for (var row in this.data)
      {
        manufactIndexes.forEach((value) =>
        {
          array.push(this.data[row][Number(value)])
        })
      }
    } 
  }
```

but what this ends up doing as I realize now is pushing all the data from all the column values into all of the arrays is there a step I am missing so that I can accomplish what I am trying to achieve in separating the data in to different arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are performing the same operation for each `manufacturersArrays` without any condition.

One way to do it is maintain a map of columns that you are interested and their arrays. See below:

```js
const data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
];

function columnsWithManufacturer() {
  return new Set([0, 1, 4]);
}

function pushIntoSeparateArrays() {
  const columns = columnsWithManufacturer();
  const interestingColumns = new Map();
  
  columns.forEach(column => {
    const array = [];
    interestingColumns.set(column, array);

    data.forEach(row => {
      const cellValue = row[column];
      array.push(cellValue);
    });
  });
  
  return interestingColumns;
}

const interestingColumns = pushIntoSeparateArrays();
console.log(Array.from(interestingColumns.get(0)));
console.log(Array.from(interestingColumns.get(1)));
console.log(Array.from(interestingColumns.get(4)));
```

Comment: this is absolutely fantastic actually I did not know this was what mapping was used for in JS. Was wondering though can each of these arrays be saved into their own variables with the number of arrays being dependent on the number of values in the set? Or is that something I would probably have to ask another question for

Comment: Nevermind actually I can just reiterate over the set and use proper *ngFor statements to achieve what I am looking for